# Cannot import multi_gpu_model from keras.utils

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, gpu

I have tensorflow-gpu 1.2.1 and keras on ubuntu 16.04.

I am not able to perform:

```
from kears.utils import multi_gpu_model
```

Has anyone had success with multi_gpu_model as described in their documentation's FAQ section?

I have a 4 GPU machine with 4 GeForce GTX 1080 Ti cards and want to use all of them.

Here's the error I get:

```
import keras.utils.multi_gpu_model

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0174878249b1> in <module>()
----> 1 import keras.utils.multi_gpu_model
      2 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.multi_gpu_model'
```

I can import keras and keras.utils successfully.

Comment: It would help if you provided the error you get from that line.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-db20c2d72799> in <module>()
----> 1 from keras.utils import multi_gpu_model
      2 

ImportError: cannot import name 'multi_gpu_model'

Comment: Please edit the question with this new information (there's an "edit" link below the question) instead of providing it in comments. It will help people who can answer this question find the information more quickly.

Comment: Ok, will do! Thanks.

Comment: Do you use `from kears.utils import multi_gpu_model` or `import keras.utils.multi_gpu_model`? `multi_gpu_model` is a function, so you can't use the latter.

Comment: Also please check your Keras version. You need to install the latest version from GitHub in order to use this function. Even the latest released Keras 2.0.8 is not new enough.

Answer (score 8):

```
pip uninstall keras 
pip install keras==2.2.4
```

this helped me ...
working on keras hrnetv2

Answer (score 3):

for Tensorflow 2.7.0 this works:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
```

Answer (score 2):

This function was added on October 11, and there have been no Keras releases that include it. Currently the last Keras release is 2.0.8 released on Aug 25, 2017.

Your only options are to wait until a release is made, or to use a Keras 
version directly from git master.

Comment: Thanks you Matias. I installed the latest version from git and the function is working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

To close this issue: I installed the latest version of Keras from github and got the multi_gpu_model module working as expected.

```
pip install git+git://github.com/fchollet/keras.git --upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

You could reinstall tensorflow-estimator and keras like this:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator
pip install tensorflow-estimator
pip uninstall keras
pip install keras
```

I was able to resolve the issue by this.