# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, nvidia

I am tyring to execute this code in anaconda Spyder

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import keras
from keras.models import Model
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, UpSampling2D, Dropout, LeakyReLU, BatchNormalization, Activation, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model  --->error
```

This code is giving error at this line

```
from keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
```

The error is

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils'

How to resolve this issue?

**I have Tried**

I ran the command for installing tensorflow-gpu

```
pip3 install tensorflow-gpu
```

But it is giving following the error and execution stops

```
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Using cached tensorflow-gpu-2.12.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [39 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 35, in __init__
          parsed = parse_requirement(requirement_string)
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 64, in parse_requirement
          return _parse_requirement(Tokenizer(source, rules=DEFAULT_RULES))
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 82, in _parse_requirement
          url, specifier, marker = _parse_requirement_details(tokenizer)
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 126, in _parse_requirement_details
          marker = _parse_requirement_marker(
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 147, in _parse_requirement_marker
          tokenizer.raise_syntax_error(
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_tokenizer.py", line 163, in raise_syntax_error
          raise ParserSyntaxError(
      setuptools.extern.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
          python_version>"3.7"
                        ^

      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ovwye3d5\tensorflow-gpu_8fc59815d9a64f798e39953c26d47c5b\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
          setuptools.setup()
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 106, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 77, in _install_setup_requires
          dist.parse_config_files(ignore_option_errors=True)
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 910, in parse_config_files
          self._finalize_requires()
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 607, in _finalize_requires
          self._move_install_requirements_markers()
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 647, in _move_install_requirements_markers
          inst_reqs = list(_reqs.parse(spec_inst_reqs))
        File "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 37, in __init__
          raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
      setuptools.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
          python_version>"3.7"
                        ^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Note: My pc dont have **nvidia GUP** but it **radeon GPU**

Comment: Does this solve your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840037/cannot-import-multi-gpu-model-from-keras-utils

Comment: I already tried it. But did not work .I have installed lasted version of Anaconda on my system.

Comment: Is it necessary for our pc to have GPU  for running this command `pip install tensorflow-gpu` ?

Comment: pip install tensorflow-gpu==version .It will work!

Comment: Yes, it should ..make sure to check the compatibility of versions

Answer (score 0):

**For the First Error :**

You are getting this error because `multi_gpu_model` is deprecated to use in Tensorflow 2.x.

[multi_gpu_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/multi_gpu_model) api is used in TensorFlow 1.x version and replaced with `tf.distribute.Strategy` api in TensorFlow 2.x to distribute training across multiple GPUs, multiple machines, or TPUs.

You can use `MirroredStrategy` of Distributed training strategies which support synchronous distributed training on multiple GPUs on one machine. It creates one replica per GPU device.

Please have a look at the [Distributed training](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) link for more details.

**For the Second Error :**

TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on [native-Windows](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native). So installing `tensorflow-gpu 2.12` for GPU support will not work in Winodws OS.